# db2 query group by and distinct

Tags: sql, db2

```
date  shift   emp      revty
d1     s1    emp1     RL
d1     s1    emp1     RA
d1     s1    emp1     AA
d1     s1    emp1     AJ
d1     s1    emp1     RD
d1     s1    emp2     RL
d1     s1    emp2     RA
d1     s1    emp2     AA
d1     s1    emp2     AJ
d1     s1    emp2     RD
d2     s1    emp1     RL
d2     s1    emp1     RA
d2     s1    emp1     AA
d2     s1    emp1     AJ


select distinct date,shift,
```

where for every distinct date and shift i will be having (RL,RA,AA,AJ,RD) or (RL,RA,AA,AJ) or (RD).

1)so if for a particular date and shift has (RL,RA,AA,AJ,RD) then it's ARR-DEP as yes and other column ARR and DEP as NO(refer below o/p)
2)so if for a particular date and shift has (RL,RA,AA,AJ) then it's ARR as yes and other column ARR-DEP and DEP as NO(refer below o/p)
3)so if for a particular date and shift has (RD) then it's DEPas yes and other column ARR-DEP and ARR as NO(refer below o/p)

so my query result should be

```
Date  shift     ARR-DEP     ARR    DEP
d1      s1        YES       NO      NO
d1      s2         NO      YES      NO
```

this is what i tried its not working

```
select distinct shift,date, 
CASE WHEN REVTY in('RL','RA','RA','AJ','RD') then "ARR-DEP" 
WHEN REVTY in('RL','RA','RA','AJ') then "ARR" 
WHEN REVTY in ('RD') then "DEP" 
end
 as type
from test al group by SHIFT,DATE,type;
```

Comment: Type? Is that the same as revty?

Comment: @jarlh if u try to understand question from my query i believe you won't get the question. please read the description and sample "my query result should be" part.

Comment: Your table doesn't have shift s2. Where is that coming from?

Comment: @TahTatsumoto that is sample data representation in my table. its not complete data present in the table. so the format is what i put. i may be having different combinations of shifts and dates. (d1,s1)(d2,s1)(d2.s2)(d1,s2) etc i need to fetch distinct of this combination. hope you understood.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select t.date, t.shift,
       (case when count(distinct case when revty in ('RL', 'RA', 'AA', 'AJ', 'RD') then revty end) = 5
             then 'YES' else 'NO'
        end) as ARR_DEP,
       (case when count(distinct case when revty in ('RL', 'RA', 'RA', 'AJ') then revty end) = 4 and
                  count(distinct revty) = 4
             then 'YES' else 'NO'
        end) as arr,
       (case when min(revty) = max(revty) and min(revty) = 'RD'
             then 'YES' else 'NO'
        end) as dep
from test t
group by t.date, t.shift;
```

Comment: don't you need a max or min around the case statements?

Comment: @Hogan . . . No.  All the columns referred to are aggregated.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select tmp.date, tmp.shift, 
case when tmp.ARR_DEP='YES' then 'YES' else 'NO' end ARR_DEP,
case when tmp.ARR_DEP='NO' and tmp.ARR='YES' then 'YES' else 'NO' end ARR,
case when tmp.ARR_DEP='NO' and tmp.ARR='NO' and tmp.DEP='YES' then 'YES' else 'NO' end DEP
from (

      select t.date, t.shift,
             (case when count(distinct case when revty in ('RL', 'RA', 'AA', 'AJ', 'RD') then revty else null end) = 5 then 'YES' else 'NO' end) as ARR_DEP,
             (case when count(distinct case when revty in ('RL', 'RA', 'RA', 'AJ') then revty else null end) = 4 then 'YES' else 'NO' end) as ARR,
             (case when count(case when revty='RD' then revty else null end)>0 then 'YES' else 'NO' end) as DEP
      from test t
      group by t.date, t.shift
) tmp
```